# Clues for this Set Proof?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

For any set $A$, let $T(A)$ be the set consisting of all sets $S \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$ that satisfy the following conditions:

- (i) $\emptyset \in S$
- (ii) $A \in S$
- (iii) $\forall X, Y \in S, (X \cup Y) \in S$
- (iv) $\forall X, Y \in S, (X \cap Y) \in S$

**Prove that:**

$\forall S_1, S_2 \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}), [(S_1 \in T(\mathbb{R})) \land (S_2 \in T(\mathbb{R}))] \implies [(S_1 \cup S_2) \in T(\mathbb{R})]$.

**Attempt:**

First, I noticed that $T$ is sort of like a power set of power sets except with these extra conditions.

I tried starting with property (iii) and using it on both conditions on the left hand side of the implication but reached a dead end?

Comment: Are you sure you mean unions? Because the statement is false. Take $S_1 = \{\varnothing, \{0\}, \mathbb{R}\}$ and $S_2 = \{\varnothing,\{1\},\mathbb{R}\}$. Then $S_1$ and $S_2$ are both in $T(\mathbb{R})$, but their union is not, because the union contains $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ but not $\{0\}\cup\{1\}$, so it fails (iii). Now, on the other hand, if you were trying to prove that $S_1\cap S_2\in T(\mathbb{R})$....

Comment: Oh, thank you very much!

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Again, thanks for the help. In future, when you first saw the problem, what went through your mind? I'm trying to improve my proof-writing abilities.

Comment: What went through my mind is that something was amiss; because if you take one set from $S_1$ and one set from $S_2$, there is absolutely no reason to expect their union to be an element $S_1\cup S_2$. At that point, you want to see if you can construct a counterexample.

Comment: Here’s what my advisor, George Bergman, likes to say: try really hard to prove it; if you run into a dead end, try to see what is going wrong, and try to use it to construct a counterexample. Try really hard to build the counterexample. If you can’t, then try to figure out what is going wrong with your construction, to see if that gives you a clue to complete the proof. And so on. Try working on the problem from both ends, but not just pushing, but if you can’t push it through, take a step back and see if you can figure out *why* you can’t push it through.

Comment: To add on what @Arturo wrote, [here is my take on how to solve your problems](http://karagila.org/2015/how-to-solve-your-problems/).

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys!

Answer (score 0):

A true proposition is
$\forall S_1, S_2 \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}), [(S_1 \in T(\mathbb{R})) \land (S_2 \in T(\mathbb{R}))] \implies [(S_1 \cap S_2) \in T(\mathbb{R})]$.